# How to copy the permission of root to current user?

Tags: permissions, chmod

I made a mistake. I copied a directory with many sub-directories and files using the sudo command. Consequently only root has permissions to do anything with the files.

Can I somehow duplicate the permissions to root for everyone/myself, in a recursive manner?

Comment: Do you want to grant permissions to another user, but still keep the files owned by root, or do you want to give the files new ownership as the originally intended user?

Comment: @DonSimon, grant permissions, but if changing ownership will do the job, it's ok with me.

Comment: Could you be more specific about what you did to copy the files (where from, where to, command used if any, etc)

Comment: @Wilf, I have a second drive, it was just partitioned. I mounted one of the partitions, and tried to paste the folder from a pen drive. It did not work. So I opened a terminal, and used `sudo nautilus` to copy the data. It was a mistake, I should have used gksudo.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Copying things as root will make things become owned by root *(gksudo I think is just to stop program settings etc becoming owned by root - see [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/270006/why-user-should-never-use-normal-sudo-to-start-graphical-application))* - you should be able to fix it using the following :

```
sudo chown -R $USER:$USER /<PATH>/<TO>/<COPIED>/<FOLDER>
```

It:

- Uses [chown](http://ss64.com/bash/chown.html)
- `-R` recursively modifies directories and files
- `$USER` is replaced with your username by the shell (command line, bash etc), so it tells it to make the files' and folders' user and group IDs your user's.
- Carries it out on the specified path - e.g.`/<PATH>/<TO>/<COPIED>/<FOLDER>`. Do not do it on just `/`, `/usr` etc, as it probably will break the system.

---

For example:

```
$ touch file
$ sudo cp file filert
$ ls -l | grep file
-rw-rw-r--.  1 wilf wilf         0 Jul  2 09:42 file
-rw-r--r--.  1 root root         0 Jul  2 09:43 filert
```

The above commands. create a file called `file`, copy it as root to `filert`, then displays the file properties. When files are copied as root, the resulting file should be owned by root - this is what happened to your files. With the above example, `filert` can be made usable by a normal user using:

```
$ sudo chown $USER:$USER filert 
$ ls -l | grep file
-rw-rw-r--.  1 wilf wilf         0 Jul  2 09:42 file
-rw-r--r--.  1 wilf wilf         0 Jul  2 09:43 filert
```